# Unity C#, не работает метод в экземпляре класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

Компилятор не ругается, просто не работают все методы.

> Класс с методом

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Move(float Speed, GameObject Player)
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, 
        Player.transform.position, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

> Экземпляр

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    Enemy zombie;
    [SerializeField] private float Speed;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject Player;
    void Start()
    {
        zombie = new Enemy();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        zombie.Move(Speed, Player);
    }
}
```

Comment: Типы, наследуемые от `MonoBehaviour` нельзя просто так создать конструктором `new [ClassName]()`. Для движка этот класс является компонентом. И он должен находиться на объекте `GameObject`. В Вашем случае лучше инстанцировать врагов из префаба, в котором уже будет находиться компонент `Enemy`. Либо добавлять его [`AddComponent()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас оба класса наследуют MonoBehaviour. Работа с ними не такая как с обычными классами. Вы не можете создавать через new  их экземпляры. 
Если хотите работать с ними как с обычными классами c# вам стоит убрать наследование MonoBehaviour. Вам важно понять что конкретно вы хотите. Что бы логика исполнялась  на сцене нужно наследовать MonoBehaviour и тогда вам стоит почитать как взять со сцены ссылку на MonoBehaviour. 
Строчка

```
zombie = new Enemy();
```

не нужна

Что бы взять ссылку на Zombie вам нужно или передать его через инспектор. Или использовать `FindObjectOfType` или `FindObjectWithTag`

Comment: Я не понимаю, можешь объяснить для тупых, что-бы можно было создать экземпляр нужно убрать наследование MonoBehaviour, но без него у меня не будет работать логика.

Comment: `zombie = GetComponent<Enemy>(); if (zombie == null) zombie = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Enemy)) as Enemy`;

Comment: @Ruft см коммент выше